# C- Program skips a scanf request in Main

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   /* for malloc */
#include <ctype.h>

struct employee
 {
 char first_name[10];
 char last_name[10];
 long id_number;
 float wage;
 float hours;
 float overtime;
 float gross;

 struct employee *next;
 };

 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /*                                                                             */
 /* FUNCTION:  print_list                                                       */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will print the contents of a linked             */
 /*               list.  It will traverse the list from beginning to the        */
 /*               end, printing the contents at each node.                      */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* PARAMETERS:   emp1 - pointer to a linked list                               */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                          */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* CALLS:        None                                                          */
 /*                                                                             */
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 void print_list(struct employee *emp1)
 {
    struct employee *tmp;   /* tmp pointer value to current node */
    int i = 0;              /* counts the nodes printed          */

    /* Start a beginning of list and print out each value               */
    /* loop until tmp points to null (remember null is 0 or false)      */
    for(tmp = emp1; tmp ; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        i++;

        /* TODO - print other members as well */
        printf("\nEmployee ID: %6d, Wage: %8.2f, Hours: %5.2f\n",tmp->id_number,
                                                  tmp->wage,tmp->hours);
    }

    printf("\n\nTotal Number of Employees = %d\n", i);

  }

  /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*                                                                            */
 /* FUNCTION:  main                                                            */
  /*                                                                            */
 /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will prompt the user for an employee           */
 /*               id and wage until the user indicates they are finished.      */
 /*               At that point, a list of id and wages will be                */
 /*               generated.                                                   */
 /*                                                                            */
 /* PARAMETERS:   None                                                         */
 /*                                                                            */
  /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                         */
 /*                                                                            */
 /* CALLS:        print_list                                                   */
 /*                                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main ()
{

char   answer[80];       /* to see if the user wants to add more employees */
int    more_data = 1;    /* flag to check if another employee is to be processed */
char   value;             /* gets the first character of answer */

struct employee *current_ptr,   /* pointer to current node */
                *head_ptr;       /* always points to first node */

  /* Set up storage for first node */
head_ptr = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
current_ptr = head_ptr;

while (more_data)
{
   /* Read in Employee ID and Hourly Wage */

    printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
    scanf("%li", & current_ptr -> id_number);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly wage: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> wage);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly hours: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> hours);

    printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
    scanf(" %c", & current_ptr -> first_name);

    printf("\nEnter Last Name: ");
    scanf("%c", & current_ptr -> last_name);


    printf("Would you like to add another employee? (y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", answer);

    /* Ask user if they want to add another employee */
    if ((value = toupper(answer[0])) != 'Y')
       {
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) NULL;
       more_data = 0; 
       }
    else
       {
       /* set the next pointer of the current node to point to the new node */
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
      /* move the current node pointer to the new node */
       current_ptr = current_ptr->next;
       }
} /* while */

/* print out listing of all employee id's and wages that were entered */
print_list(head_ptr);

 printf("\n\nEnd of program\n");

 return 0;
  }
```

I want to start reading in the ifnormation for First_name and last_name, but when I prompt the user for first_name, i type the value in, hit enter, and then it skips the last_name request. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Hint: You still have a newline character in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%s` instead of `%c` to read strings.  When you read `%c` you are only getting one character, and leaving the rest in the buffer.

```
printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
scanf("%s", &current_ptr->first_name);
```

Comment: darn, I knew it was a rookie mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

according to understanding of your question. I think you should call fflush() function before scanf() statement. May be your problem will solve but i am not sure. please make sure syntax of this function.

Answer (score 0):

as c.fogelklou mentioned, use `%s` for a string and `%c` for a character. however, `scanf` can cause buffer overflow attack, thus, i suggest you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) and [this page](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html) to know how to avoid this.